# ORACLE : Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: linux, jdbc, oracle10g

We are getting this error sporadically. With the same TNS, we are able to make proper connections to the database. But we see this in the logs while make connections some times. Following is the stack trace. This is db connection to Oracle from a Linux machine and java application Any help is appreciated.

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:297)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:221)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:157)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:94)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1567)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:478)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:347)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:404)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:189)
>       at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:165)

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be a Cisco UCCX issue, would it? I am having the same issue, same error message, and it happens sporadically. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: We cleared the DNS cache and that helped!

Answer (score 11):

try following

1. (obvious) IP address is incorrect - try PING
2. The port is not open, or is blocked by a firewall - try TELNET
3. The DB listener is not running or is binding to a different network
   interface - again, TELNET should confirm this (also use Oracle client
   tools to connect)
4. No local ports are available for the out-going connection
   (unlikely) - only if you're making thousands of connections, or
   creating hundreds of new connections every minute.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. Items 1 - 4 any of these issues will make this happen sporadically? TELNET works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the connection pool runs out of connections...
When DBMS listener's incoming request buffer is overloaded by many simultaneous connection requests. It will fail some of them.

you can have the thread sleep a bit (half-second to a second or so) between successive connection requests. After that, don't close connections until they're broken. Keep them and re-use them.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2540479, maybe you must change listener.ora's file host parameter to your host parameter. You can check that what parameter is your hostname in windows, cmd>hostname

Comment: Check it why? It's about a different message.

Comment: @EJB Different message descriptions does not mean that can't help us in different situations. Just it helped me, that's all.