# getting exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in simple jdbc program

Tags: java, oracle10g

I was trying to run a simple jdbc code [ using jdk 1.6, oracle 10g] as,

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.text.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
/**
 * @author animark
 */
public class CallableStatementEx1 {
    public CallableStatementEx1(){;}

public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        Connection con=null;
        String url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:orcl" ;   
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"scott","password");

        String query="update emp set HIREDATE=?,ENAME=? where empno=?";

        //Step1: Get PreparedStatement
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);

        //Prepare java.sql.Date object
        /*
        This logic shows how to convert simple String that is in 
        dd-MM-yyyy format into Date object
        */
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        java.util.Date d=sdf.parse("26-12-2001");
        java.sql.Date newdate=new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

        //Step2: set parameters
        ps.setDate(1,newdate);
        ps.setString(2,"animark");
        ps.setInt(3,7839);

        //Step3: execute the query
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("record updated count: "+i);
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
                    e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }//main
}//class
```

The code is getting compiled properly. But when I'm trying to run it, i'm getting the following exception..

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at javaapplication2.CallableStatementEx1.main(CallableStatementEx1.java:19)
```

I've checked the oracle services and all of them are up and running.

Also, please find the contents of other files as

=================================================================================
tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

====================================================================================

```
sqlnet.ora


# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
================================================================================

# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

===============================================================================

I'm being able to connect to the instance "orcl" using credentials "scott/password", but when i'm trying to connect using statement

SQL> connect sys/password@orcl as sysdba

I'm getting the following error..
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect

### descriptor.

I've also run LSNRCTL for orcl and found

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 22-JUL-2012 13:42:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORACLE : Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324125/oracle-io-exception-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection)

Comment: The output of lsnrctl seems to indicate that it does not have a "orcl" service. Maybe this is a better question for Serverfault (more Oracle administration then programming related).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
On the 4 points given in the response of the referred question, please find my comments.

Its a local host, so i guess 1 and 2 are not required here.

For 3, I've already tried to connect to orcl using sql-plus and got successfully connected using the credentials "scott/password" but failed using "sys/password".

For 4, Its Local host, so is it required to be checked? Even if it is,please help me with a little more details on how i can check that.

Comment: @Thilo: but the tnsora shows that there's only one instance with service as "orcl"...

Comment: A quick help is really appreciated as the whole of the work is stuck on this. Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: Someone must be having something to say on this i hope..

Answer (score 4):

Try taking the `//` out of the connection URL.  Instead of

```
    String url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:orcl" ;
```

try

```
    String url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" ;
```