# Spring JDBC connection on startup no issue but when an insert or update happens issue

Tags: spring, jdbc

i have a Spring web application. Spring 3.0. When server startup i am not getting any Database connection exception but when i try to access the application i am getting below exception.

Please help me on this.

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy21.createUser(Unknown Source)
com.merck.ushh.onemerck.common.ValidateRequest.createUserInDBAndIsso(ValidateRequest.java:428)
com.merck.ushh.onemerck.resources.ServicesImpl.create(ServicesImpl.java:116)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy21.createUser(Unknown Source)
com.merck.ushh.onemerck.common.ValidateRequest.createUserInDBAndIsso(ValidateRequest.java:428)
com.merck.ushh.onemerck.resources.ServicesImpl.create(ServicesImpl.java:116)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.&lt;init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.&lt;init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy21.createUser(Unknown Source)
    com.merck.ushh.onemerck.common.ValidateRequest.createUserInDBAndIsso(ValidateRequest.java:428)
    com.merck.ushh.onemerck.resources.ServicesImpl.create(ServicesImpl.java:116)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:187)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Questions with the error "The Network Adapter cannot establish the connection" have been asked numerous times on Stack Overflow before.  Here are a few examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574414/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025014/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127839/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324125/ .  Have you been through all of the answers to these questions (and all answers to other questions mentioning the same error message) and confirmed that none of them work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC The Network Adapter could not establish the connection/Connection reset/recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758574/jdbc-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-connection-reset-rec)

Comment: Hi Luke, i havegone through all these links and found something might help you to answer for my question. i tried to ping the database server from my application server i got this respone 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms. which is good but when try using telnet dbservername then i get this telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out. so can you help me on which part i should be focused to solve this issue?